# how to install swiper version 6.8.4 modules?

Tags: reactjs, react-swiper

`import 'swiper/components/mousewheel/mousewheel.min.css';`

*Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/components/mousewheel/mousewheel.min.css'*

i need to use mousewheel from swiper in my react app, but i don't know how to install it

Comment: From the command line, run: `npm i swiper`

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want to use Swiper 6, import it this way:

```
// swiper bundle styles
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css'

// swiper core styles
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'

// modules styles
import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.min.css'

// swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'

// swiper modules you want to use
import SwiperCore, { Mousewheel, Pagination } from 'swiper';
```

Modules need to be installed using SwiperCore.use() method on Swiper class:

```
SwiperCore.use([Mousewheel, Pagination]);

const App = () => {
  return (
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={"auto"}
        pagination={{
            clickable: true,
          }}
        mousewheel={true}
        className="mySwiper"
      > ...
```